# How to delete the AMI and snapshot simultaneously during terraform destroy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

In my case, AWS AMI was created by `packer` and deleting the image via terraform (0.11.6 version) using `terraform import` and `terraform destroy`. Once after importing the existing AMI, I could see the `root_snapshot_id` details inside the `.tfstate` file. But during the `terraform destroy`, only the AMI is getting deleted and the associated snapshot could not be deleted.

To achieve in a tricky way, I was trying to import the snapshot using terraform. But unfortunately, terraform does not support the `import` option for snapshots.

**Expected:**
AMI should be deregistered and delete the appropriate snapshot simultaneously.

**Actual result:** Only AMI is deleted and snapshot still exists.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Importing the AMI into state only to destroy it seems like a bad use case for Terraform compared to simpler things such as using the AWS CLI.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I'm trying to destroy both AMI and its snapshot. Yes, I can use AWS CLI to perform the snapshot deletion. But we are not supposed to use AWS CLI in our environment. So trying to find some other way to achieve it within terraform.

Comment: You should probably raise this on the AWS provider issue tracker and see what their opinion is.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thanks for the suggestion. Let me check with them.

Comment: Jump out the idea you have, think to manage these support jobs with other ways, for example, set a lambda function to detect and delete old ami and its snapshots

Comment: @BMW yeah we can. But, managing our environment completely via infrastructure as a code (Terraform). As per the design we are not supposed to use AWS CLI or any Lambda functions. That's the problem here. So finding the way to do it within terraform.